# How to run Tomcat 9 as another user in a Java EE project in Netbeans 17

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I wish to run Tomcat 9 as the tomcat user (now it automatically use my currently logged on the user **robtot**) when starting a Java EE project in NetBeans 17. This causes the **Apache Tomcat or TomEE** output in NetBeans to permission errors to the logfiles:

```
...
Starting service [Catalina]
Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58 (Ubuntu)]
Failed to open access log file [/usr/share/tomcat9/logs/localhost_access_log.2023-03-20.txt] Note: running as user [robtot]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat9/logs/localhost_access_log.2023-03-20.txt (Permission denied)
...
```

I was hoping if I run Tomcat from NetBeans as the tomcat user, then the permission issues are fixed.

**Note: I have added user robtot to the tomcat group.**

Apart from permissions errors for log files, the **Apache Tomcat or TomEE** output seems fine. However, the **TestProject (debug)** log looks like this:

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat
Starting of Tomcat failed.
/home/TestProject/server/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1196: Starting of Tomcat failed.
```

The lines 1196 of build-impl.xml is the DEBUGGING SECTION:

```
<target depends="init,-init-cos,compile,compile-jsps,-do-compile-single-jsp,-pre-dist,-do-tmp-dist-with-manifest,-do-tmp-dist-without-manifest" description="Debug project in IDE." if="netbeans.home" name="debug">
<nbstartserver debugmode="true"/> // THIS IS LINE 1196
<antcall target="connect-debugger"/>
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart} debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="true"/>
<antcall target="debug-display-browser-old" />
<antcall target="debug-display-browser"/>
<antcall target="connect-client-debugger"/>
</target>
```

These are the owners and permissions of the tomcat9 folders and content:

**/usr/share/tomcat9**

```
drwxr-xr-x root tomcat bin/
lrwxrwxrwx root tomcat conf/
-rw-r--r-- root tomcat default.template
drwxr-xr-x root tomcat etc/
drwxr-xr-x root tomcat lib/
-rw-r--r-- root tomcat logrotate.template
lrwxrwxrwx tomcat tomcat logs
lrwxrwxrwx tomcat tomcat temp
lrwxrwxrwx tomcat tomcat webapps
lrwxrwxrwx tomcat tomcat work
```

**/etc/tomcat9**

```
drwxrwxrwx root tomcat Catalina/
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat catalina.properties
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat context.xml
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat jaspic-providers.xml
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat logging.properties
drwxrwxrwx root tomcat policy.d/
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat server.xml
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat tomcat-users.xml
-rwxrwxrwx root tomcat web.xml
```

**/usr/share/tomcat9/logs**

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat   2129 Mar  9 13:38 catalina.2023-03-09.log.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat    733 Mar 14 18:39 catalina.2023-03-14.log.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat   1613 Mar 15 14:19 catalina.2023-03-15.log.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat   3768 Mar 16 13:43 catalina.2023-03-16.log.gz*
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat   4958 Mar 17 11:18 catalina.2023-03-17.log.gz
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat adm     35438 Mar 20 08:04 catalina.2023-03-20.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat  32483 Mar 20 08:04 catalina.out*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 syslog adm    311661 Mar 20 07:21 catalina.out.1*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 syslog adm      1909 Mar 12 07:16 catalina.out.2.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat     45 Mar  9 10:28 localhost.2023-03-09.log.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat     45 Mar 15 14:03 localhost.2023-03-15.log.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat     45 Mar 16 08:00 localhost.2023-03-16.log.gz*
-rw-rw-r--  1 tomcat tomcat     45 Mar 17 09:52 localhost.2023-03-17.log.gz
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat adm         0 Mar 20 07:21 localhost.2023-03-20.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat     56 Mar  9 10:28 localhost_access_log.2023-03-09.txt.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat     56 Mar 15 14:03 localhost_access_log.2023-03-15.txt.gz*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat   3074 Mar 16 13:37 localhost_access_log.2023-03-16.txt.gz*
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat tomcat   5542 Mar 17 14:34 localhost_access_log.2023-03-17.txt.gz
-rw-r-----  1 tomcat adm       875 Mar 20 07:22 localhost_access_log.2023-03-20.txt
```

Here is is the logs settings for server.xml:

```
<Valve className=org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b@ />
```

And in related posts I also seen that people sometimes mention to show the Connector settings from server.xml:

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" address="::1" port="8009" server="Apache-Coyote/1.1" secretRequired="false" redirectPort="8443" />
```

In addition, I noticed that people mention that tomcat-users.xml must be set correctly. This is mine:

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user password="<mypassword>" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script" username="robtot" />
```

I have stopped the existing (locally) running tomcat9 and apache2 services. I use:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Tomcat 9.0.58
- NetBeans IDE 17 (downloaded via snap and also tried manual download from official repo)
- JavaEE 5

There are similar threads out there, but none of them solves my issue:

- [Netbeans won't start Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335964/netbeans-wont-start-tomcat)
- [Starting of Tomcat failed from Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225764/starting-of-tomcat-failed-from-netbeans)

Thanks!

---

***Update #1:*** I have tried to execute netbeans from terminal by doing as root:

```
cd /usr/lib/apache-netbeans/bin
./netbeans
```

The log permission are gone when doing this as root, but the *Tomcat failed to start* message in **TestProject (debug)** output still exist, resulting in tomcat not starting properly. Also, it is not possible to login as tomcat as it is a nologin user. The question is now more turning into why Tomcat fails to start.

Comment: Not familiar with NetBeans - how do **you** run it? Do you have the path to the netbeans executable? Do you have sudo privileges?

Comment: I simply open up NetBeans IDE as the robtot user and run it in debug/non-debug mode (CTRL + F5). NetBeans itself is installed via snap.

Comment: Is running netbeans as tomcat user an option? Although this feels like a hack. Did you check the permissions of the log files themselves, not just the tomcat\logs folder?

Comment: I added the a view of the tomcat\logs folder and the permission of the content. Good catch, thanks. I have no idea how to run the NetBeans IDE as a tomcat user while being logged on as another user. That is one of the main questions of this topic :) Hopefully someone else knows.

Comment: You can run it as tomcat user, provided you have sudo privileges, and you know where the executable is, that's why I asked in the previous comment. You can try executing `where netbeans` - if you can't find anything, the executable might be in the `/usr/local/netbeans*` folder. What OS are you on? Help me help you, then I can write an answer.

Comment: I found the executable for Ubuntu. It exists in /usr/lib/apache-netbeans/bin/netbeans and it is possible to open netbeans from there doing ./netbeans. However, as root the permission issues are gone, but "Tomcat failed to start" is still there, and it is not possible to change user to tomcat because tomcat is a nologin user. I receive this message doing "sudo su tomcat": "This account is currently not available.". Reas for this is explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486346/this-account-is-currently-not-available-error-when-trying-to-ssh

Comment: OK - my idea was to open netbeans as tomcat user, which you should be able to do with `sudo -u tomcat /usr/lib/apache-netbeans/bin/netbeans`. What happens if you try this?

Comment: root@ubuntu-2204:/usr/lib/apache-netbeans/bin# sudo -u tomcat /usr/lib/apache-netbeans/bin/netbeans resulting:


```WARNING: package com.apple.eio not in java.desktop
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.```